# Will removing a cabinet wall create structural issues?

Tags: cabinets

I have a terrible blind corner in my kitchen and I am trying to figure out the best way to handle it. My top idea right now is to cut out the wall separating it from another space and put in a mid height L shaped shelf and then the whole space can be accessed from either door. My concern is that I will create a structural issue if I cut the wall out.

This is the wall I want to cut out.

[image]

Picture of the corner from the outside:

[image]

Picture from the inside of the cabinet that is really deep and essentially useless:

[image]

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I think the OP is referring to an internal wall *of the cabinet itself*, and not the wall of the house it's mounted to.

Comment: Right, internal cabinet wall. Nothing with the actual house. I just want to my sure my countertop won’t be unstable

Comment: So this isn't "create a pass through between kitchen and another room" but rather "turn two *base* cabinets into one". Aha! In that case, it depends on whether the walls are actually providing support - they actually very likely are these days, but not always, and if they are whether removing one will matter much. Hard to guess...but my hunch is *probably* OK.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That’s what I was thinking. If not, guess I get to do my kitchen remodel sooner rather than later.  If it helps, I am pretty sure the cabinets are original to the house in 88.

Comment: It might be handy to give us a picture of the entire corner, in addition to the tight zoom shot. Helps to have a "big picture". Literally.

Comment: I think it'll be hard to answer this question from pictures, but your best chance is if you remove all the drawers, shelves, inserts and perhaps even the doors and provide well lit, well focused photos of the cabinet structure from the inside.  What we're looking for is this: Most modern cabinets have their structure in the side walls and front frame.  Some older ones have a full frame and no structural walls.  I wouldn't hold my breath but you may be able to do something.   Can you clarify in your question that "another space" means a dead space currently cut off from both adjacent cabinets?

Answer (score 1):

Completely editing my answer after seeing new picture.  Original answer assumed there was completely dead space in the corner.  New picture shows a *fairly common* configuration where one cabinet extends into the corner space.  Just do a search for "corner cabinet swing out".  There are swing-out organizer for this configuration, where only one cabinet extends into the corner and the other adjacent one has a wall.

Breaking open the other cabinet and building a huge corner shelf will not particularly solve your problem, as shown in the new picture.  You'll still have a hard-to-access abyss in the back of the cabinet.  A swingout, made for the arrangement you now have, will solve it.

Here's a picture of one type of swingout.  This one has two "cars" that come out separately.  There are also ones with a big S-shaped shelf that swings out in one piece.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In our area the builders normally put a "lazy susan" , a rotating cabinet in such a corner . It makes reasonable use of the volume which is otherwise pretty difficult to use.

Comment: Based on the additional pictures, it looks like the standard base cabinet on the left and the unusual, extended cabinet on the right should be removed and the 2 of them replaced with a standard "lazy Susan" corner cabinet. Based on exact sizing, there may need to be a narrow cabinet or filler piece put in to fill the entire space.